# Decorating a function with parameters not working as expected

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a decorator that has to add HTML tags to a string.
The decorator works fine if it has to wrap a fixed string.

```
def tagger(fn):
    def wrapper(*x):
        return "<strong>" + fn() + "</strong>"
    return wrapper

@tagger
def foo():
    return 'Hello'

print(foo())
```

But if I remove the fixed string and add a parameter to the function `foo()`, the decorator doesn't work.

```
def tagger(fn):
    def wrapper(*x):
        return "<strong>" + fn() + "</strong>"
    return wrapper

@tagger
def foo(x):
    return str(x)

print(foo('Hello'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fn()` calls `foo()`. `foo` requires a parameter, but you're not passing one. Did you mean to pass the `*x` through? `fn(*x)`.

Comment: TNX. I've missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never pass on the parameter. The expression `fn()` in the wrapper is a call to the original, decorated function, but you don't pass the arguments on.

Your decorator wrapper accepts arbitrary positional arguments as `*x`, pass those into the `fn()` call:

```
def tagger(fn):
    def wrapper(*x):
        return "<strong>" + fn(*x) + "</strong>"
    return wrapper
```

For completion sake, you also want to pass on *keyword* arguments, and use the more common `args` and `kwargs` names for these variables:

```
def tagger(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return "<strong>" + fn(*args, **kwargs) + "</strong>"
    return wrapper
```

Now the decorator can be used on functions that take keyword arguments as well.

Answer (score 3):

You missed forwarding any *args into the `fn()` call.

```
def tagger(fn):
        def wrapper(*x):
               return "<strong>" + fn(*x) + "</strong>"  # <-- This will call foo(*x)
        return wrapper
@tagger
def foo(x):
    return str(x)

print(foo('Hello'))
```